# Remove UISearchDisplayController translucent overlay prior to search

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin

I'm working with a situation similar to the screenshot below ([taken from another question asked about the gap at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660506/uisearchdisplaycontroller-gap-between-overlay-and-bar)) .

[image: I want to remove this gap. It's the worst.]

I know how to make the `UISearchDisplayController`'s `tableView` show up in whatever frame someone wanted, and that's great, but now I'm dealing with this black translucent overlay that I cannot get to move.

No amount of changing any frame for a `tableView` in any order is fixing it. The only thing that fixes it is changing `EdgesForExtendedLayout` property for the parent controller, and this is **not an option** given the way everything else on the page and application is displayed.

So, how can I remove or shift the translucent overlay to whatever Y position I want?